# How to automate WINSCP file transfer using Java?

Tags: java, automation, winscp

I need to automate transfer of files from my local machine to a web server.For that I need to login into winscp and copy the file from my machine to some folder in server.

Can anyone please help regarding how to automate this using java only?

Comment: Have a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries available in Java to perform file transfers over protocols like SSH. One such example is JSch.
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

If you are looking for a specific protocol or architectural process, you will need to provide some additional information about what it is you are trying to accomplish in Java (ie nightly batch process, ETL, watching a directory and moving files as they show up, etc).

Comment: Tried using jsch and it resolved my problem.Thanks for the help